# prevent path deformation made by preserveAspectRatio="none"

Tags: svg

I'd like to prevent `<path>` elements from stretching caused by`preserveAspectRatio="none"` on `<svg>` tag.
I've found nearly perfect solution adding this attribute to `<path>` elements:

```
vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
```

But I need them to be scalable with `transform="scale()"` which is also disabled or more precisely their `stroke-width` are fixed and not scalable. So, my question is:
Is there any way to prevent stretching but not zooming?

Ok, to make it more clear: https://codepen.io/lukydorny/pen/aNYOdW

I would like to shape a path by different `viewBox` width and height (2nd image) but I need horizontal line to be of same width as vertical(3rd image). And then I wish I was able to scale it exactly the same way as original path(4th image) which is disabled as you can see in the last image.

Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Here I made example to demonstrate my problem. https://codepen.io/lukydorny/pen/aNYOdW

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "stretching but not zooming". You codepen doesn't really help.  What do you want to jappen. Perhaps you could attach an image that demonstrates what you want to achieve.

Comment: There is describing title on every image.

Comment: I would like to shape a path by different viewBox width and height (2nd image) but I need horizontal line to be of same width as vertical(3rd image). And then I wish I was able to scale it exactly the same way as original path(4th image) which is disabled as you can see in the last image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this simply by defining the SVG element like this:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
    style="display:block">

    ... your SVG paths code here

</svg>
```

Notice the "viewBox" size should be the size of your "svg document" (maximum x and maximum y values).

This preserves the aspect ratio you define; however, be aware that your paths created should comply with the size you define, else it may cause problems.

To "zoom" the whole graphic, simply change with width & height of the SVG element, or its parent element, or use "scale()"  inside the SVG, or with JavaScript as you normally would.

Comment: It's not what I meant. For some reasons I need to have variable height in viewBox e.g. in one case "0 0 1920 1080" and "0 0 1920 540" in another. A change of path's shape is desirable. My problem is that the path is wider in horizontal line than in vertical. It's exactly n-times wider when viewBox height is n-times lower.

Comment: Try changing the viewBox size at the same time - see what happens? would be interesting to know ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean "viewBox size"?

Comment: the svg element property: `viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"` above

Answer (score 0):

**Would this option work?**

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px
}
```

```html
<div title='original path' style='float:left;'>
<svg width=192px height=54px viewBox='0 0 200 200'>
  <path style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(50, 122, 97); stroke-width: 8px; fill: none;" d="m30 68.709l5,0,4.111,0,3.444,0,3.555,0,4.111,0.071,5,0.214,5.222,0.428,5.222,0.571,5,0.642,4.778,0.571,4.778,0.428,4.778,0.214,5.111,0.071,4.778,0,4.333,0,3.667,0,3.444,0,3.333,0,3.222,0,3,0,2.556,0,2.111,-0.071,1.889,-0.214,1.778,-0.499,1.778,-0.785,1.445,-1.07,1.111,-1.284,0.778,-1.498,0.556,-2.069,0.444,-2.64,0.222,-3.211,0.111,-2.997,0,-2.569,0,-1.998,0,-1.998,0,-2.283,0,-2.64,0,-2.497,0,-2.069,0,-1.569,-0.556,-1.284,-1.556,-1.07,-3,-0.785,-3.778,-0.499,-4.222,-0.214,-4.222,-0.071,-4.889,0,-5.333,0,-6,0,-5.778,-0.071,-5.778,-0.214,-5.556,-0.428,-5.556,-0.571,-5.889,-0.571,-5.889,-0.428,-5.778,-0.214,-4.445,-0.143,-3.333,-0.143,-2.444,-0.214,-2.333,-0.214,-2.333,-0.214,-2.222,-0.214,-2,-0.214,-1.778,-0.214,-1.667,-0.214,-1.778,-0.071,-1.778,0.357,-1.667,1.926,-1.222,3.781,-0.778,5.494,-0.333,5.28,-0.111,4.495,0,3.568,0,3.496,0,4.21,0,4.923,0,5.494,0,4.78,0,3.996,0,3.282,0,3.14,0,3.354,0,3.496,0.111,3.568,0.333,2.854,0.667,2.069,1.111,1.427,1.445,1.213,1.778,0.999,1.778,0.713,1.889,0.499,1.889,0.499,2.111,0.499,2.889,0.571,4.111,0.571,5.778,0.713,6.778,0.713,7.333,0.642,7,0.428,6.333,0.214,5.778,0.071,5.667,0,6.111,0,7.111,0,8.111,0,8.556,0,7.333,0,5.667,-0.071,4.444,-0.143,4.333,-0.285,4.556,-0.285,4.667,-0.285,4.556,-0.143,4.333,-0.143,4,-0.143,3.333,-0.214,2,-0.143,0,0"></path>
</svg>
</div>
<div title='original path' style='float:left;'>
<svg width=192px height=108px viewBox='0 0 200 200'>
  <path style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round; opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(50, 122, 97); stroke-width: 8px; fill: none;" d="m30 68.709l5,0,4.111,0,3.444,0,3.555,0,4.111,0.071,5,0.214,5.222,0.428,5.222,0.571,5,0.642,4.778,0.571,4.778,0.428,4.778,0.214,5.111,0.071,4.778,0,4.333,0,3.667,0,3.444,0,3.333,0,3.222,0,3,0,2.556,0,2.111,-0.071,1.889,-0.214,1.778,-0.499,1.778,-0.785,1.445,-1.07,1.111,-1.284,0.778,-1.498,0.556,-2.069,0.444,-2.64,0.222,-3.211,0.111,-2.997,0,-2.569,0,-1.998,0,-1.998,0,-2.283,0,-2.64,0,-2.497,0,-2.069,0,-1.569,-0.556,-1.284,-1.556,-1.07,-3,-0.785,-3.778,-0.499,-4.222,-0.214,-4.222,-0.071,-4.889,0,-5.333,0,-6,0,-5.778,-0.071,-5.778,-0.214,-5.556,-0.428,-5.556,-0.571,-5.889,-0.571,-5.889,-0.428,-5.778,-0.214,-4.445,-0.143,-3.333,-0.143,-2.444,-0.214,-2.333,-0.214,-2.333,-0.214,-2.222,-0.214,-2,-0.214,-1.778,-0.214,-1.667,-0.214,-1.778,-0.071,-1.778,0.357,-1.667,1.926,-1.222,3.781,-0.778,5.494,-0.333,5.28,-0.111,4.495,0,3.568,0,3.496,0,4.21,0,4.923,0,5.494,0,4.78,0,3.996,0,3.282,0,3.14,0,3.354,0,3.496,0.111,3.568,0.333,2.854,0.667,2.069,1.111,1.427,1.445,1.213,1.778,0.999,1.778,0.713,1.889,0.499,1.889,0.499,2.111,0.499,2.889,0.571,4.111,0.571,5.778,0.713,6.778,0.713,7.333,0.642,7,0.428,6.333,0.214,5.778,0.071,5.667,0,6.111,0,7.111,0,8.111,0,8.556,0,7.333,0,5.667,-0.071,4.444,-0.143,4.333,-0.285,4.556,-0.285,4.667,-0.285,4.556,-0.143,4.333,-0.143,4,-0.143,3.333,-0.214,2,-0.143,0,0"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```